# Vagrant invalid range of IP

Tags: networking, vagrant, metasploit

```
root  pop-os  /etc  mkdir vbox
root  pop-os  /etc  cd vbox/
root  pop-os  /etc/vbox  nano networks.conf

* 10.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.0/16
* 2001::/64
```

I used this solution to solve the problem with Vagrant and then I run it again:

```
 root  pop-os  ../metasploitable3-workspace  curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rapid7/metasploitable3/master/Vagrantfile && vagrant up
```

The error:

```
The IP address configured for the host-only network is not within the
allowed ranges. Please update the address used to be within the allowed
ranges and run the command again.

  Address: 172.28.128.3
  Ranges: 10.0.0.0/8, 192.168.0.0/16, 2001::/64

Valid ranges can be modified in the /etc/vbox/networks.conf file. For
more information including valid format see:

  https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly
```

I also tried the following as I saw somewhere but the same error.

`* 172.28.128.0/24`

or
`* 0.0.0.0/0 ::/0`

I am following the repo:https://github.com/rapid7/metasploitable3
to install metasploitable 3 for learning purposes. (why is this difficult I mean).
Packer - Vagrant - VirtualBox are installed.

Comment: The error message tells you two ways to fix the problem. Have you tried any of those two ways? What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Did you read my post? `I also tried the following as I saw somewhere but the same error.`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
* 10.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.0/16 172.16.0.0/12
```

Proper definition of the three Reserved Private Network spaces as defined in RFC1918 and asserted by IANA